# What can be deduced from $P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, independence

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$

(1) If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A) = 0$ or $P(B) = 0$.

$\quad$ **True,** $P(A \cap B)= 0 =P(A)\cdot P(B)$

(2) If $A$ = S(sample space), then $P(B) = 0$

$\quad$ **True, since** $P(A \cap B) = 0$

(3)  If $P(A) >P(B) > 0$, then $A$ and $B$ are not independent

$\quad$ **True, if both are positive, then $P(A \cap B) > 0$, which contradicts $P(A \cap B) = 0$**

(4) If $P(A) \neq P(B)$, then $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive

$\quad$ **True, this is vacuously true since $P(A \cap B)= 0$, $A$ and $B$ are already mutually exclusive**

Is my reasoning correct? I am unsure about (4), is there a counterexample that disproves (4)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we know $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$, but that doesn't necessarily mean $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  Choose a real number $X$ uniformly at random from $[0,1]$. Let $A$ be the event $X\in[0,\frac23]$ and let $B$ be the event $X\in[\frac23,1]$.  $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$, but $A\cap B$ is the event that $X=\frac23$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the third one is incorrect, if you choose $B=A^{c}$ then they are dependent, and you can build an example where both of probabilities is positive, but of course still $P(A\cap B)=0$

As for the fourth one, I think the counter example comes from not countable sample spaces, where you can consider:
A is distributed uniformly over [0,1] ($P(A)=1$)
and B is the rational numbers set ($\mathbb{Q}$) (*)
Then you get $$P(A\cup B)= P(A)+P(B) =1$$
and $1=P(A)\neq P(B)=0$
but of course $B\subseteq A$

(*) or any other countable set

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).
$

- (1) is correct, as you observed that the assumption $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ is equivalent to $P(A\cap B)=0$, and independence says $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.
- (2) is correct since $P(B)=P(A\cup B)=0$.
- (3) is correct since it is the contrapositive of (1).
- (4) No, $P(A\cap B)=0$ does *not* imply that $A\cap B=\emptyset$. A counterexample: $A=\{0\le X\le 0\}$ and $B=\{0\le X<\infty\}$ where $X$ is a random variable with normal distribution.  Then in this example $P(A)\ne P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)=0$. But $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: For (3), what if P(B) = P(A'), then wouldn't A and B(ie A') be dependent events?

Comment: that is: $P(A\cap B)=0$ implies that the "measure " of $A \cap B$ is null.

Comment: @GCab, sorry what do you mean by "measure"?

Comment: @user624: I don't understand your question. What I mean is that (1) implies that if both $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are not zero, then $A$ and $B$ must be dependent.

Comment: I mean the measure in term of probability: although $A \cap B$ is not an empty set, it is a set with null measure = null probability.

Comment: @mrsamy, I understand that (3) is the contrapositive of (1), but for example, P(A) = 0.6, P(B) = P(A') = 0.4. Then, P(A) > P(B) > 0, P(A $\cap$ B) = $0$, A and B are independent events?

Comment: @user624: No. If $P(A)=0.6$ and $P(B)=P(A^c)=1-P(A)=0.4$. Then you must have that $A$ and $B$ are dependent by (1). The fact that $P(A\cap B)=0$ alone does not say anything about independence of the two events.

Answer (score 0):

We have P(A or B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A and B)

So, P(A or B)=P(A)+P(B) implies P(A and B)=0

As already answered here, note that it does not mean (A and B) is an impossible event.

Comment: Thanks, so am I right that 1,2 are true and 3,4 would be false?